# Magento 1.9 product Zoom issue

Tags: product, zoom

I am facing an issue with our product zoom functionality. 
[image]

You can see under zoomed image we can see qty + and - signs clearly. 
Can someone assist me with how to fix this?

Comment: i think issues is css qty div added z-index.so you remove z-index...

Comment: What is the URL of your page or the name of the zoom script that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange family.

I think there can be a few solutions.

**First Solution:** *Zoom* CSS selector z-index value should be larger than *Qty* selector z-index value.

**Second Solution:** *Qty* CSS selector z-index value should be removed.

**Third Solution:** *Qty* CSS selector z-index value should be smaller than *Zoom* selector z-index value.

Hope this will help you. Thanks